# Primeng p-toast show in inner div

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeng p-toast in angular application.

```
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

export class UsermgmtComponent { 
  //some other code

  clickToShowMessage(){
    this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary: 'Successful', detail: 'User created', life: 5000});
  }
}
```

However, when inspect in chrome browser, the toast shows in inner div:

```
<body>
<div>  //first div, css: {position: fixed; z-index:10}

</div>
<div>  //second div, css: {position: relative; z-index:1}
  <div>
    //toast html code is created here
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I expect the toast shows in the same level with the first div:

```
<body>
<div>  //first div
</div>
<div>
</div>
//toast html code is expected to be created here
</body>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It makes sense that the toast will be generated within the scope of the top component of your project and not outside of it. You're importing `ToastModule` into a module, not using it as an external CSS/JS. However, it is also expected that the toast would be `absolute`ly `position`ed, so it shouldn't really matter. What are you trying to archieve visually that doesn't work with the current code?

Comment: Please refer to this image:[link](https://i.imgur.com/rzf5pPW.png)  Current result, the first div is hiding the toast. The expected result is the toast should show above the first div.

Comment: what is the z-index of the first div?

Comment: First div has z-index of 10. I have try to put the z-index to toast. However, even the toast div has higher z-index, for example, 1000, the toast is still behind first div.

Comment: What is the `position` value of your "first div"? Please share the code.

Comment: The first div has position of relative. I have added css information in my question. Please refer to my question. The first div is the toolbar, and second div is the content.